# How do I buy a life insurance policy as a collateral?

Tags: taxes, investing, mortgage, banking, financial-literacy

I’m almost done paying my home, my wife wants to sell it and buy a bigger house using the money from the sale?  Someone told me to borrow against the house instead of selling it, and then purchase a life insurance policy as a collateral. Is this smart?

Comment: what country are you in? You added a "taxes" tag - what's the taxes relevance to the question?

Comment: The country has to be identified to understand the tax impact of this plan.

Comment: This seems to be an X/Y question -- you are asking about a specific approach (which may not even be valid) rather than asking how to accomplish what you want to do or whether what you want to do will work.

Comment: @littleadv Borrowing against the house, instead of selling it, may avoid incurring a tax liability on any appreciation in its value. There may be further tax benefits with life insurance.

Comment: @user71659 that depends on the jurisdiction. In some places selling a home to buy a new one is not a taxable transaction, but buying a second home while keeping an existing one - is.

Answer (score 2):

It's very common to buy a house, and then sometime later sell this house and use the equity as a down payment on a bigger house. For example, you buy a house that costs $100,000. Over some period of time you pay off $30,000 of the mortgage, So you still owe $70,000 and you have $30,000 in equity. Then you sell this house and buy a bigger house that costs, say, $150,000, You use $30,000 equity from the first house as a down payment on the second house.

If you're lucky, the value of the house has gone up while you were living there, so while you bought it for $100,000 it's now worth say $120,000. As you still owe $70,000, your equity is $50,000, the $30,000 you paid off plus the $20,000 that the value increased.

It is certainly possible to not sell the first house but borrow against it to get the down payment for the new house. But then you owe money on the new mortgage, you still owe the old mortgage, plus you owe on the home equity loan. The advantage is that you now own two houses. The disadvantage is that you are now paying for two houses.

Do you have some plan what you will do with the old house? If it's just going to sit there empty, this would be a very foolish thing to do. You'd be paying for a substantial asset that you are not using.

If you can afford two mortgages and you have some reason to want two houses, could be realistic. Like if you want a regular home and a vacation home.

If you are thinking that you will rent out the old house and make income from it, okay, that's a viable plan. But being a landlord is a difficult business. I've seen some posts on this site and elsewhere where people seem to think that you just sit back and collect rent checks and it's like free money. No, it isn't. If you want to get into a discussion of the pros and cons of the landlord business, that's probably another question. Suffice it to say that it's a business that involves significant work and significant risk.

I don't see why you'd need a life insurance policy as collateral. I don't see why the bank would insist on any collateral besides the house itself. Mortgages are among the safest loans for a bank to make because if you don't pay it back, they can seize the house and sell it. The house is the collateral.

If you're borrowing more money than the combined value of the two houses, maybe the bank would insist on a life insurance policy as collateral. I've never had a bank ask me for such, but I don't know what country you're in or how much money you're talking about. In the US, most consumer loans are either secured by the value of the thing you're buying, like a house or a car or a boat, or they are "signature loans" secured only by the borrower's good faith and promise to pay. But maybe in some circumstances or in other countries they'd insist on some other collateral. Has a bank told you that you would need a life insurance policy as collateral, or is this just something you were told by a friend who doesn't necessarily know?

Comment: Life insurance as a collateral is a weird concept to me... How is it being used? The bank will chop off your head to collect the life insurance if you don't pay?

Comment: @littleadv I can't think of a time when a bank has demanded I get a life insurance policy for collateral for a loan. Just hearing the idea, I'm guessing that the point is that if you die, the cash is paid to your estate so the bank can get their money. Like if you die so you're no longer able to work and make payments, they'd still get their money. Yeah, if you just quit paying, a life insurance policy wouldn't do the bank any good. Well, maybe if you had a whole life policy, they could collect something.

Comment: @littleadv The confusion here is the two types of life insurance. You two are thinking of term life insurance, which works like automobile insurance. The second type is permanent life insurance. Here, you pay into the policy in a lump sum, or at some fixed schedule, and the money is invested. When you reach the maturity date or you die early (the life insurance portion), the value is paid out. Thus, there is a cash value of the policy which [can be used for collateral](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/111714/what-collateral-assignment-life-insurance.asp).

Comment: @user71659 oh, so insurance as a saving vehicle? But wouldn't a collateral require an already accumulated value?

Comment: @littleadv Yes, permanent life insurance is a long-term/retirement investment. It's just like using your home for collateral (e.g. HELOC), the lender would look at the value the time of the loan, considering the fact that for both a mortgage and PLI, you have mandatory payments in the future. You might have paid into your home for years. You may have put a large down payment when you bought the house. Or you might have no equity and signed your home mortgage yesterday, in which case they'd refuse to take it as collateral.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "permanent life insurance". Maybe that's a term used in the UK, or maybe there are insurance options I'm not aware of. There's a thing called "whole life", where you pay monthly premiums and a portion of your premium is invested, so that the policy accumulates cash value. Not sure if "permanent" is another name for "whole" or if that's something different. A big catch to using whole life as collateral for a loan is that the value of a whole life policy builds slowly, while the amount you owe on a loan declines. So in the early days of the loan there wouldn't ...

Comment: ... be enough value, while at some point there would be more value than you need.

Comment: But as I said earlier, I think it's all a moot point. If you bought a house with a mortgage, the house is the collateral. You don't need additional collateral. The life insurance policy would be superfluous.

Comment: @Jay Permanent life insurance refers to investment-type life insurance generally. Whole life insurance is a type of PLI where there is no maturity date (or is set extremely high, e.g. 120). Money is paid in on a fixed basis, and paid out either by death, or by withdrawal. Another type of PLI is "universal life insurance" with features such as voluntary contributions that increase benefits, benefits indexed to interest rates/equities. An "endowment life insurance policy" has a fixed, relatively short end date, recently they've been marketed for college savings plan.

Comment: @Jay The problem with your plan is that I do not think its common in the US to take existing home equity as collateral for another home, you have to go through cash via a home equity loan or something like life insurance collateral. The issue is risk: if we have another mortgage crisis, the bank is going to get stuck with two homes they can't sell. Loss of value of both homes are likely highly correlated.

Comment: I think "permanent" here means a Whole Life policy. See other questions/answers for discussion of how those actually work. Basically they're bundling of (usually inferior) savings with insurance, whose one real advantage is that they force regular savings if you don't have the self-discipline to manage saving for yourself. Some cultures seem to believe they are something more than that... In any case, a Whole Life account may have accumulated significant value over the years. Whether a bank would accept that as collateral is up to the bank.

Comment: @user71659 Sorry if I wasn't clear. You're misunderstanding what I'm saying. You own house #1. You have a mortgage, and your collateral is the house, house #1. Now you decide to keep this house and buy a second house. You get a mortgage on house #2. The collateral on house #2 is THAT house, house #2. The collateral on each mortgage is the house that that mortgage was used to buy. Perhaps there is some special case where you would need other collateral or additional collateral, but I've never come across such a case.

Comment: @keshlam But if you take out the whole life policy for the purpose of using as collateral to buy a house ... I don't see how that would work. On the day that you buy the policy, your equity in the policy is zero or close to zero, but your debt on the house is very large, the full value of the house minus whatever your down payment was. Depending on the cost of the house and the size of the policy, it's possible that eventually you'll accumulate enough in the whole life policy to cover the cost of the house, but that could take many years. ...

Comment: ... And why? Why not just use the house as collateral, like about 99% of people who get mortgages do? I don't see why the proposed scheme would be necessary or advantageous even if it did work.

Comment: As I said in the edit, it _wouldn't_ work; there would be no accumulated value yet. But it's the only way I can make any sense of the phrase being quoted. As to why: I think that the idea was to leverage it as a way to borrow more than the bank would normally be willing to loan... which, even if it did work, would probably not be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what the life insurance thing is about. (See edit below.)

Keeping the old house only makes sense if you are going to use that house for something that is worth continuing to pay mortgage on it. The most common version of that is renting it out. However, if you do that you are starting a *business*, with all the hassles and risks that come with running a business, even if you pay some of the income to have someone else manage the property for you; see past answers about what's involved before jumping on that idea.

If you sell the place, you would pay off its mortgage, and use whatever is left to help fund buying the larger house. It would be a good idea to check that this will in fact be enough that you'll be able to afford the mortgage on the new place. Remember that while the price you can ask for your house has gone up over the years, so has the price of everything else on the market.

EDIT: It has been pointed out that a Whole Life policy (see other questions/answers about that) could have accumulated enough saved value that a bank *might* accept it as collateral. But that's up to the individual bank, and you'd have to have one of these accounts for many years to save up enough that this would make any significant difference in your borrowing ability. Buying it now does nothing for you.